# Any way to decompile binary resource file built with ancient compiler?

Tags: c, windows, resources, porting

I'm trying to resurrect a 1990's application that was built with Borland Turbo C++ (version unknown, maybe 3.0, maybe 4.5?), and apparently targeted for Windows 3.1.

The project contains a single .c file, and a single .res file. Rather than try to locate the ancient compiler, I've tweaked the C source into compatibility with MinGW gcc ver 4.5.2, thinking I could rebuild it for win32. Unfortunately, this is one of those windows programs where the main window is a dialog box, and the dialog specifications are embedded in the .res file. Of course modern MinGW gcc doesn't understand the old .res format.

So is there a way to recover an .rc file from a 1990's vintage Borland .res file?  I know there will be other problems compiling old 16 bit windows code like this, but I can deal with that later (it's only 2K loc), right now the stumbling block is this resource file.

**somewhat later ..**

I have found 'Turbo C 3.1', but this thing is a trip. It can actually compile for 16-bit windows, the resulting executables requiring an NTVDM to run under XP, but the concept is proved. Tried it on a simple windows hello-world, and it worked.

Anyway, the problem is still the .res file! There was a project (.prj) file with the aforementioned material, but it apparently calls out the .rc source file. I know with gcc, I can link an already compiled resource file into an executable, but heck if I can figure out the strange command line for 'bcc' to do it. To get an idea how odd it is, bcc uses -W as a flag to 'create windows application'. It must be possible. Anybody remember?

(fwiw- i think there may be better tags for this. feel free to re-tag.)

Comment: Can you post the .res file?  What exactly are you trying to recover?  Strings? Images? Dialogs?

Comment: Have you attempted to use: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/owlnext/index.php?title=Convert_Borland_C%2B%2B_resource_files_to_Visual_C%2B%2B

Comment: Do you have a copy of the .exe?  If so, it might easier to extract resources from the .exe

Comment: @selbie - Inspection of the .c file leads me to believe there may be 5 dialogs and an icon. I don't care about the icon.

Comment: @cbranch - I do have the .exe, and tried feeding it to ResHacker, but was met with "This is not a Win32 executable file". I fairly sure it's a DOS 6 vintage .exe file.

Comment: You could also try loading Win3.1 on a VM, and installing fishing for a copy of Turbo C++ on the interwebs.

Comment: @JustJeff: Visual Studio is able to open .exe files and show resources.  I wasn't 100% sure it supports 16-bit applications, but I just tried with one of my old apps from the '90s, and it worked.  This app was built with Borland C++ 4.5, and I was able to open the .exe in Visual Studio 2008 and view dialogs, string tables, bitmaps, etc.

Comment: Yes, the Borland compiler might have saved/read the resource file in a strange format, but it had to *compile* the resources into the EXE in the standard format. Which means that any application capable of reading resources directly from a binary should be able to view them just fine. You might need a time machine, though, to find one that can read 16-bit executables.

Answer (score 1):

Open Watcom C/C++'s Resource Editor (wre.exe) seems to be able to open 16-bit .res files. If the latest version doesn't work fully (which isn't totally unexpected as very few people work with 16-bit resource files), try earlier ones.